# How do I redirect requests for certain images in ASP.NET MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm integrating a 3rd party jquery plugin into a page on my ASP.NET MVC website and I have found that it expects that the images are in an img folder relative to the page it is on. It generates img tags looking like this:

```
<img src="img/blah.jpg">
```

The trouble is, my page is at a URL like `mysite.com/mycontroller/view/id` and so there is no easy way of putting the img folder in the right place for it to pick up the images. I need the img tags to be like this:

```
<img src="/Content/img/blah.jpg">
```

Obviously I could edit the 3rd party javascript to output a different path every time it creates an img tag, but I am wondering whether there is a better way in ASP.NET MVC (perhaps with rerouting?).

(I am very new to ASP.NET MVC and web development, so please tell me if I'm going about this in completely the wrong way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend avoiding trying to fix this via routing.  It's going to be easier and most performant to edit the script to have the path be correct.  Fixing it in the client script is likely as easy as a find and replace or just editing a single string object.

Comment: thanks, I'm still very much a beginner at this. After implementing your suggestion, I discovered that the majority of the images were specified in the css anyway.